# Live alert/notifications for iot solutions (DJANGO + UBUNTU)

Tags: ubuntu, websocket, cron, django-channels

Hi everyone i am kinda newbie about that staff and open for any/all help,

Firstly let me shortly summarize that what i want to do and what i have done so far. I am trying to develop a web platform that will be a gui for the users. Users can see their datas which is collected by iot endnodes, as a charts table etc. Also users can set alarm condition, e.g. "*if temperature is over 21 send e-mail*"

At that point i do some search about live-notification and findout websockets, redis and channels things. I tried all of it together in one temperature application and success to get e-mail alert which is triggered by treshold value i will share my codes below.

The problem is my websocket handshaking working only if client is on page. I mean my users should not keep open the web platform to get alert.

I am using Ubuntu OS and Nginx webserver service. My datas comes from influxdb so i am checking last data on influxdb if the value is over 21 want to trigger the alarm, simple.

I am not sure about the method maybe it is wrong and not suitable for my case so i am open for alternatives for example i heard smth about ubuntu cron job. Can it be suitable for my case ?

CODES________

***consumers.py***

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer, WebsocketConsumer
import json
from random import randint
from asyncio import sleep
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
from itertools import zip_longest
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail


lora_host = 'My_Server_Adress'

class GraphConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
    await self.accept()
    client = InfluxDBClient(host=lora_host, port=8086)
    client.switch_database('loradb')
    temperature = client.query(
        "SELECT * From device_frmpayload_data_Temperature WHERE time > now() - 1d ORDER BY time DESC")
    temperatureDev1 = temperature.get_points(tags={'dev_eui': '000950df9be2733e'})
    dict = []
    dict.append(next(temperatureDev1))
    timePrevious = str(dict).split("'time': '", 1)[1].split(".", 1)[0].split("T")
    timePrev = timePrevious[1]
    xTime = ''
    alertStatus = 0
    while True:
        temperature = client.query("SELECT * From device_frmpayload_data_Temperature WHERE time > now() - 1d ORDER BY time DESC")
        temperatureDev1 = temperature.get_points(tags={'dev_eui': '000950df9be2733e'})
        dict = []
        dict.append(next(temperatureDev1))
        val = float(str(dict).split("'value': ", 1)[1].split("}", 1)[0])
        rTime = str(dict).split("'time': '", 1)[1].split(".", 1)[0]

        if val > 21 and rTime != xTime and alertStatus == 0:
            alertStatus = 1
            xTime = rTime
            subject = 'Alerted'
            message = 'Temperature is too high'
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = ['recipient_1@gmail.com']
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
        if val < 21 and alertStatus == 1:
            alertStatus = 0
            subject = 'OK'
            message = 'Temperature is fixed'
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = ['recipient_1@gmail.com']
            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)

        timeABC = str(dict).split("'time': '", 1)[1].split(".", 1)[0].split("T")

        if timeABC[1] != timePrev:
            timePrev = timeABC[1]
            await self.send(json.dumps({'value': val, 'timeABC': timeABC[1]}))
            await sleep(20)
        else:
            await sleep(20)
```

***Settings.py/Redis-channel***

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
    'CONFIG': {
        'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 6379)]
     }
  }
}
```

Like i said i am open for any simple suitable solutions.
Thanks a lot from now.

Answer (score 0):

The job about detect condition and send email can't write in websocket Consumer logic. if the browser close, the websocket disconnect, the job is killed.

You need use [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to work that job.

- websocket logic real-time just show temp.
- celery logic detect condition and send email.

Comment: Thank you so much for solution suggestion. Appreciated